# Pandas boolean filtering order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I met the problem with Pandas. 
For instance, I have dataframe and I want to filter its.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [i for i in range(5)], 
                   'B': [i ** 2 for i in range(5)]}) 

df[(df.A > 2) & (df.apply(lambda row: print('call'), axis=1))]
```

But why does it work so? Why second statement executes for all rows? I thought than Pandas can filter by order with logic and (operator &)

[image]

Can someone explain me? How can I use filter in one dataframe without reassigning dataframe?

Comment: You are printing `call`, not returning anything from your `lambda` function.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can copy your terminal output here without posting a picture

Comment: For correct working need return boolean from custom function.

Comment: If you know print expression will return None object which is interpreted like False.

Comment: If you want I could define the function which will print the something and return boolean value

Answer (score 0):

`print` returns `None` and so

```
df[(df.A > 2) & (df.apply(lambda row: print('call'), axis=1))]
```

is the same as

```
df[(df.A > 2) & pd.Series([None]*5)]
```

which is the same as

```
df[pd.Series([None]*5)]
```

all of the elements are interpreted as `False` so you get the empty `DataFrame`

Answer (score 0):

Or you can do this :

```
df.loc[df.A > 2, "isCalled"] = 'called'
```

And for the other rows :

```
df.loc[~df.A > 2, "isCalled"] = 'not called'
```